# What are the common points between physical optics and geometric optics?

Tags: optics, visible-light, geometric-optics

I am trying to write a paper about light, I want to discuss the two way of studying light, the [physical/wave optics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_optics) and the [geometric/ray optics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_optics), but I want to write a general introduction about them, what are the common points between them?

Answer (score 1):

The common thing about ray and wave optics is that they are just different representations of the symplectic group. Paraxial ray optics in 3-d is the study of the finite dimensional representation of the symplectic group Sp(4,R) carried on phase space. Wave optics in the Fresnel approximation is the study of the infinite-dimensional unitary representations of Sp(4,R) carried on the space of wave functions.